# Getting error (OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied) while tryng to install selenium on jupyter notebook using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, package

I have used `! pip install selenium` and getting the following error-

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\certifi-2020.12.5-py3.8.egg-info\\dependency_links.txt'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Not getting how to consider '--user' while installing the package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, this helped

```
pip install selenium --user
```